# "Cannot start application" in NetBeans using Java Web Start

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, web-applications, java-web-start

Last week I had a similar problem. I'm new to Java Web Start so I created a simple program that launches a `JFrame` with a `JLabel`, a `JButton` and two `JTextField`s. When I try to start the program it launches a window with the message "Cannot start application" and it gives me two options "OK" and "Details".

This is what it shows when I click "Details":

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "\Users\JuanCarlos\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HolaMundo\dist"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebaseEx(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebase(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the JFrame code:

```
  package holamundo;

  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;


 public class HelloWorld extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form HelloWorld
 */
public HelloWorld() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    holaLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    nombreTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    okButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    resultadoTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    holaLabel.setText("HOLA");

    nombreTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            nombreTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    okButton.setText("OK");
    okButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            okButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    resultadoTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            resultadoTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(150, 150, 150)
                    .addComponent(okButton))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(81, 81, 81)
                    .addComponent(holaLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(resultadoTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 97, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(nombreTextField))))
            .addContainerGap(183, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(81, 81, 81)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(holaLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(nombreTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
            .addComponent(okButton)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(resultadoTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(107, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void nombreTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                               

private void okButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String aux;
    aux = this.nombreTextField.getText();
    //System.out.println(co.cat("Pelos", aux));
    this.resultadoTextField.setText(co.cat("Hola ",aux));

}                                        

private void resultadoTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   

}                                                  

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new HelloWorld().setVisible(true);
        }
    });


}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public javax.swing.JLabel holaLabel;
public javax.swing.JTextField nombreTextField;
public javax.swing.JButton okButton;
public javax.swing.JTextField resultadoTextField;
// End of variables declaration                   

 public static Concatenar co=new Concatenar();

 }
```

This is the other class im using:

```
package holamundo;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Concatenar {
    String cat(String a, String b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

This is the jnlp file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <jnlp       codebase="file:/C:/Users/JuanCarlos/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HolaMundo/dist/"    href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>HolaMundo</title>
    <vendor>JuanCarlos</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>HolaMundo</description>
    <description kind="short">HolaMundo</description>
<offline-allowed/>
</information>
<update check="background"/>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="HolaMundo.jar" main="true"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="holamundo.HelloWorld">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Which line is line 65?

Comment: @Frakcool   '.addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()'

Comment: Is that your whole error log? It says you're writing a String somewhere it expects a number. Especifically an int

Comment: What versions of JRE and JDK? See https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236765 Suggested resolution is to upgrade JDK and JRE

Comment: @Frakcool thats error, i checked what you point out, and everything its fine, i dont know whats failing.

Comment: @copeg  JRE and JDK up to date.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: .. Also add the JNLP content here, so we can check it. I think this error results from the launch file, not the app.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hi Andrew, i added the jnlp file. I'll be sure to check out your file. Thanks!

Comment: The JaNeLA tool is ***designed*** (by me) to check JNLP files (so it is better than I am). Having said that, the URI for the `codebase` appears to be incorrect format. It has `codebase="file:/C:/Users/..` where it should be `codebase="file://C:/Users/..` (count the number of `/` characters in each). If that advice does not fix the problem, use the JaNeLA tool. It is cool, calm software with better 'eyes' than my poor ones, and the analytical ..approach that I could not apply to such things (even if I wanted to!).

Comment: & see also the [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) (where I checked for that info)..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks Andrew, probably NetBeans its not generating the jnlp correctly, I tried adding the backslash and it didnt work, everytime i run the app it changes and goes back to only one backslash. I'll check out your app. Thanks!

Comment: *"probably NetBeans its not generating the jnlp correctly, .. I'll check out your app."* It's ironic. Netbeans is made by Sun/Oracle. You'd ***think*** they should be able to make a tool that can generate a valid JNLP launch file, right? The irony comes from the fact that it was seeing the crap-tastic JNLP files generated **by Netbeans** that prompted me to ***write*** the JaNeLA tool! :-/

Comment: I just uninstall and reinstall NetBeans and upgrade my JRE & JDK and still get the same error.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Do you know how to edit the .jnlp file cause I edit the file but when i run the program it changes into the default file.

Comment: @AndrewThompson also can you help me with the error messages i had been getting in JaNeLA , help page doesnt work.

Comment: Do they include the text (from memory) CVC? These are produced by an API that is used to validate XML & there should be hundreds (or thousands) of hits on the internet for them..

Comment: @AndrewThompson  
there are two errors i don't understand: `Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for '.jar'` &  `The resource download at '.jar' can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'` I did mi research but i couldn't find an answer.

Comment: They are not errors but mere optimizations.. And that explains why you cannot find information on them. They are not produced by an API but from my interpretation of how JWS works. Note that **neither one would cause an app. to fail.**